# .env variables with React returns undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a .env file in the root folder of my React.js app. A variable is declared like so:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=api-key
```

And is called like this:

```
const auth = {
  key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
};
```

But it returns undefined. Why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

Restart Your Development Server: Changes to .env files are not hot-reloaded. If you made changes to your .env file while your development server was running, those changes won't be picked up until you restart the server.

Correct .env File Location: Ensure that your .env file is located at the root of your React project (the same folder as your package.json file).